# Cannot change the value of an array in php

Tags: php

I have a global array variable I am using to store some values from a `$_POST` variable.  Because I am modifying them within an `if` statement I have used the word `global`.  I have already populated the array as `array(0,1)`.  Given that the values are modified within my `if` statements, I am still getting the initialised values that I started with.

**EDIT:**

Here is my `formHandler.php` code:

```
   // get form ID
$formID = $_GET['id'];

// create a global array
$results = array();

// check to see what ID has be retrieved
if ($formID == 1) {
    $value = $_POST['emotion'];
    $results[0] = $value;
    // 302 redirect
    header("location: page02.php?results1=$results[0]");
} 
else if ($formID == 2) {
    $value = $_POST['emotion02'];
    $results[1] = $value;
    // 302 redirect
    header("location: page03.php?&results2=$results[1]");
}
```

Here is my `page01.php` code:

```
  <h1>This is Page 01</h1>

    <form id="form" action="formHandler.php?id=1" method="POST">

            <p><input type="radio" value="happy" name="emotion">Happy
            <input type="radio" value="excited" name="emotion">Excited
            <input type="radio" value="angry" name="emotion">Angry
            <input type="radio" value="frustrated" name="emotion">Frustrated
            <input type="radio" value="miserable" name="emotion">Miserable
            <input type="radio" value="sad" name="emotion">Sad
            <input type="radio" value="tired" name="emotion">Tired
            <input type="radio" value="calm" name="emotion">Angry</p>

            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

Here is my `page02.php` code:

```
<h1>This is Page 02</h1>

    <form id="form" action="formHandler.php?id=2" method="POST">

            <p><input type="radio" value="happy" name="emotion02">Happy
            <input type="radio" value="excited" name="emotion02">Excited
            <input type="radio" value="angry" name="emotion02">Angry
            <input type="radio" value="frustrated" name="emotion02">Frustrated
            <input type="radio" value="miserable" name="emotion02">Miserable
            <input type="radio" value="sad" name="emotion02">Sad
            <input type="radio" value="tired" name="emotion02">Tired
            <input type="radio" value="calm" name="emotion02">Angry</p>

            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

Here s my `page03.php` code:

```
<?php include("formHandler.php"); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Audio Survey</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Thanks for your submission</h1>

        <?php

        $results = array();
        $results[0] = $_GET['results1'];
        $results[1] = $_GET['results2']; 

        echo "<p>" . $results[0] . " " . $results[1] . "</p>"; 

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...what are you trying to do?

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: php's variable scope is function level. Your `global` calls are utterly pointless. PHP will also NOT preserve variables between pages. Each of your scripts is completely/utterly independent of each other, and "global" does not magically preserve variables between scripts. You need to use `$_SESSION` or other external storage methods for that sort of thing.

Comment: I see, thanks.  The tutorial I was following had them within a function so I presumed that you would need them within `if` statements.  I will remove the `global` calls and look into `$_SESSION`

Comment: When you are redirecting, redirect with parameters in the URL to use the values from your FormHandler.php. For example, page03.php?Result1=x&Result2=y. Then you can display it on the page after you call them with GET.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  So I could just substitute your `x` and `y` with `page03.php?$result[0]&$result[1]`?

Comment: why are you including a file which is directing to another page?

Comment: The `$results` array doesn't even reach your thanks for submission page. It already gets redirected before doing this. Can I help this out for you with `$_SESSION` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using $_GET to get the form ID but your said it's a $_POST (method="POST") form, so the ID will never match the condition on your if statements. This should fix it:

```
$formID = $_POST['id'];
```

Also, id should be an input on the form for it to be passed as $_POST, the actual id attribute of the form wouldn't be passed to the server by itself.

If you're actually passing "?id=x" on the url from the action attribute, then please post the form HTML aswell.

AND another thing, you don't need, and shouldn't use "global", especially if the variables are in the the same file where you're calling them from.

Comment: Thanks - Yes I am passing in `?id=1` with `page01.php`, then `id=2` on `page02.php`, then `page03.php` is where I wanted to print the results.  I'm hoping that I can retrieve form information from each page then display it on the last page.  This is simply an exercise as I want to be able to have 20 pages that do the same as the ones I have just posted.

Comment: I'd still like to see your form HTML.

Comment: You have $value = $_POST['emotion02']; on the second if statement, but on page02 the field is still called emotion.

Comment: Apologies again, It is "emotion02".  Just rectified it above.  There are 6 radio buttons on both page01 and page02, but I left them out to make the code more condensed.

Comment: Don't be code shy, post everything. It's all relevant.

Comment: Ok - no problem, just posted all my edits I've done so far since starting this post.

Comment: I've just tested the whole thing on my server and it's working. I made one change though, on the first if you have  header("location: page02.php?results1=$results[0]"); I changed page02 to page03.

But... I don't see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your work - much appreciated.  I was expecting to see both results from page01 and page02 displayed on page03 e.g. [angry, sad].  I've changed to page 3 like you with `"location: page03.php?results1=$results[0]&results2=$results[1]"`, but I am only getting the last result from page02 and not page01.  Its okay as I'll just have to do some more research on this.

Comment: I finally understand your question. You want to go page by page and saving the answers. You will have to use sessions for this.

$_SESSION['results'] = array();
and then just
$_SESSION['results']['page01'] = $result;

that way you can store the results across any number of pages. But yeah, you should probably research a bit more.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help - apologies for all the confusion - I'll start looking into `$_SESSION` asap.  I can even see when I get to page03 that the `result[0]` actually equals nothing within the `url` as you say because its not being "carried over".

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need the page03.php. Just die or return the code (the html) in your formHandler.php.

Maybe this helps you too:

[$_SESSION](http://www.ayom.com/faq/variablen-ueber-mehrere-seiten-hinweg-verwenden--a-655.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have no need for global variables here, all your code is within the same scope.